# Should the [d20] tag be [d20-System] instead?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There's an infrequent but noticeable trend to use the [d20](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d20) tag on questions about dice or critical hits or the like, despite the tag being clearly labelled as specific to the d20 System:

> The d20 system, developed alongside D&D 3e, forms the mechanical backbone for a variety of RPG's entirely departed from the D&D system.

If the tag itself were [d20-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d20-system), I think this would quickly and easily make the mis-tagging go away.

I know it's not a major issue in the grand scheme of things, but it's been bugging me so I brought it here. (I'm also curious why the tag wasn't "-system" in the first place.)

Answer (score 11):

I'm for this, in part because it's less ambiguous, but also in part because of this:

> I'm also curious why the tag wasn't "-system" in the first place.

I did a brief google, and its official title *is actually* "d20 System". [Here's a Wizards page](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=d20/srdfaq/20040123a) - they don't just call it "d20".

When we create a tag for something, typically we name the tag after the official name. So aside from being clearer, [d20-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d20-system) would be *the correct tag name.*

Comment: I think the abbreviated name is a hold-over from the early days of the site; people don't usually use its full name and most tags are the "most common name" (hence [D&D-4e] rather than [D&D-4th-edition] or something), so it started out as just "[d20]". Since expanding it to the more formal name presents no problems for finding or using the tag though, there's no reason we shouldn't!

Answer (score 4):

I like the idea. It's less ambiguous without being unwieldy.

Answer (score 2):

As it is written, so let it be done.

Tag merged.